# MonacaからエクスポートしたHTMLをブラウザで動作させることは可能でしょうか？

Tags: monaca

MonacaクラウドでOnsenUIを利用したアプリケーションを作成しています。
プロジェクトをエクスポートするとwww以下にHTMLファイルやJSファイルなどがありますが、こちらのファイルをChromeやFirefoxなどのブラウザで動作させることは可能でしょうか？
ネイティブアプリケーションではなく、ブラウザで動作させたいです。

また、もし可能でしたら手順などご教示いただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

1. ブラウザで実装されているAPIのみ使用している（CordovaのAPIを利用していない）
2. サーバに配置している
3. パス指定と、それに対するディレクトリ配置が適切
4. ライブラリ含め、ファイルが全て揃っている

以上を満たすなら、サーバにアップして、適切なパーミションをつければ動作します。
一度試してみて、動かないならエラーログを確認してみると良いと思います。

Answer (score 0):

Cordovaをセットアップし、Monacaのバックアップを放り込んで
platformにbrowserを追加してビルドすればいいかと思います。
ハードウェア機能にアクセスする関数等は全滅致しますが大体動きます。